# How to simulate a WEP cracking scenario for faster cracking in local lab?

Tags: wireless, wep

I need to illustrate WEP cracking methods, I'll be using aircrack suit for that.
There is a little problem that I want to speed up the method for very fast packet capturing, since this is just an illustration and I can simulate the necessary conditions in lab, I was wondering what would be the idle environment that I need to prepare ?

Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a virtual lab, assuming that you want to demo this with no physical hardware, I would recommend getting a .pcap of actual WEP traffic (wireshark or tcpdump will do for this) and rebroadcast it with a simple python script or a tool like tcprelay.

Just setup two VMs on the same subnet and use one to broadcast and one to crack. One of the problems that people tend to run into with these demos is that you need network activity on the target access point to get enough data to perform the crack. By doing it once for real (when you generate your .pcap) and just capturing that data off in a .pcap you won't have to worry about setting up some ancillary service to generate traffic for you.  It's already done and you will know that there is enough data, very good for demo purposes.  Also, I'd recommend using Aircrack-ng over just Aircrack. Aircrack will do but it's kinda out of data.

You should be able to run a similar setup to this on laptop with VirtualBox and two stripped down linux VMs.

EDIT: 
Here are some example .pcap files for WEP breaking from http://weplab.sourceforge.net/ 
You may be able to use the weplab project to get the type of setup you're talking about right out of the box, actually. It looks like they have examples for a number of WEP attacks and pretty good documentation on how to get it all up and running.

- [weplab-64bit-AA-managed.pcap](http://weplab.sourceforge.net/caps/weplab-64bit-AA-managed.pcap)
- [weplab-64bit-aaa-managed.pcap](http://weplab.sourceforge.net/caps/weplab-64bit-aaa-managed.pcap)

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me but I am still looking for a solution to increase the data capturing rate from physical wireless router. In my setup there are 3 machines running Ubuntu one of which is used to perform the crack and other 2 are exchanging data with router for first machine to capture. I was hoping to get it done with de-authentication attack but that is not doing good enough. Can you give me any tip on that ?

Comment: something I've done in the past that has worked well, but is admittedly a bit 'rigged':
#!/bin/bash
for((;;)) 
do
curl [router_default_web_gateway_interface]
done

:-)

Best of luck with your project & presentation.

Comment: Streaming is good for traffic increase