# WEP .pcap example, need help finding one

Tags: network, wep

I first wanted to simulate a WEP wi-fi network using virtual machines and then intercept data/crack it but it seems that I need actual wireless interfaces which I do not have and using my own in my actual pc also seems like it won't work with VirtualBox. But if you know a way please do let me know.

I then found this: [How to simulate a WEP cracking scenario for faster cracking in local lab?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25987/how-to-simulate-a-wep-cracking-scenario-for-faster-cracking-in-local-lab)

I wanted to follow the steps mentioned here but I am having trouble finding a .pcap file with WEP traffic that I could get data from/an actual password or the WEP key, or something meaningful.

The overall goal is to show how vulnerable WEP is and how easy it can be to crack and intercept data.
If anyone could provide me a .pcap file with WEP traffic I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Something like this?  https://www.google.com/search?q=wep+pcap+files+download

Comment: Questions asking for the location of resources are off-topic because they do not age well, and it becomes an exercise in search query keywords.